# OpenCV 4 - cmake Python3 / library "cv2.cpython"

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I am trying to install OpenCV 4 at Ubuntu 18 and Python 3. I am following the hints from: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/

When doing the installation I am encountering two problems:
1) At the command

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \ 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \ 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \ 
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \ 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \ 
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \  
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

it seems that it is still using Python2 and misses some libraries.

2) After the build I am missing the library "cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so". How can I include it in the installation process?

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: Can you please share the output of `~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python --version`? Just trying to check all scenarios.